# Is it possible to restore a MySQL database to a previous state in time?

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I just realized that the MySQLWorkBench destroys the target (makes a replacement) when performing synchronize model.
Making changes on the source and model between synchronizations leaves you with a weird bastard.
So is it possible to return to a given snapshot in time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recent backup of the database taken using mysqldmp should be sufficient for you to restore the database to the time of the last backup.

After a restore, it's possible to roll forward changes from the binary log to a particular point in time.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

Aside from that, there is no rollback to a "snapshot in time" and no "flashback query" functionality in MySQL (at least not in the MySQL 5.1 Community Edition.)

Comment: I'm used to work with MSSql, occasionally Oracle and often envied Oracle for it's snap shot feature.
Since MySQL is new to me, i was just hoping that something similar to snap shot would be available.
Regular backups it is then.

Comment: The cost and performance of MySQL comes at a cost, such as not having an Oracle-like "flashback query" functionality. Be aware that mysqldump does NOT guarantee a consistent backup. We use InnoDB for all of our tables, and use mysqldump --single-transaction for backups.